# Batch file Mixing multiple colors

Tags: batch-file, utility

I've been wondering if someone have made a batch file utility that can mix 2 batch
colors into another color (for example: Red + Yellow to make Orange). I don't really know if its even possible or not to do such a thing, but if there is, I want to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if with "batch colors" you refer to color values of `color` command, then it is very easy to get some equivalences based on the original color table shown by `color /?` command:

```
0 = Black       8 = Gray
1 = Blue        9 = Light blue
2 = Green       A = Light green
3 = Aqua        B = Light aqua
4 = Red         C = Light red
5 = Magenta     D = Light magenta
6 = Brown       E = Yellow
7 = White       F = Bright white
```

(perhaps color names are not the same of `color /?` command, I am translating they from my Spanish Windows)

This way, we may see that Red+Yellow (4+E = 12 mod F = 2) gives Green!

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set hexa=0123456789ABCDEF
set /P "first=Enter first color (hexa digit): "
set /P "second=Enter second color (hexa digit): "
set /A sum= (0x%first% + 0x%second%) %% 16
set result=!hexa:~%sum%,1!
color %result%
echo The result is: %result%
```